# Extract Domain from DistiniguishedName using PowerShell

Tags: powershell, ou, distinguishedname

I tried the following code to extract the domain and it worked just fine when defining a variable

```
$ADS = 'CN=Lamda,OU=OU_Bloquage,DC=Adminstrateur,DC=6NLG-AD'
```

But things didn't go well when I changed `$ADS` into

```
$ADS = Get-ADUser -Identity 'Lamda' -Properties DistinguishedName |
       select DistinguishedName`
```

The result that I want to have is:

```
DC=Administrateur,DC=6NLG-AD`
```

Below is the code that I've wrote

```
$ADS = Get-ADUser -Identity 'Lamda' -Properties DistinguishedName |
       select DistinguishedName
$pattern = '(?i)DC=\w{1,}?\b'
([RegEx]::Matches($ADS, $pattern) | ForEach-Object { $_.Value }) -join ','
```

Comment: `select DistinguishedName` -> `select -Expand DistinguishedName`

Comment: as AnsgarWiechers pointed out, your problem is that your data is in a property of an object, not an object of its own. [*grin*] you can either expand the property with `Select-Object`, or address the property in your code. use `$ADS.DistinguishedName` instead of `$ADS`

Comment: I modified `select DistinguishedName -> select -Expand DistinguishedName`and tested it but the following error occurs : `Move-ADObject:Operation could not be affected because object parent was not created or was deleted  `

Comment: You are not showing us the part where you do a `Move-ADObject`. The question is only how to split the distinghuished name..

Answer (score 1):

As Ansgar Wiechers and Lee_Daily already pointed out, all you really want is the DistinghuishedName property of a user.
The `Get-ADUser` cmdlet returns this property by default, so to get it as string simply do:

```
$dn = Get-ADUser -Identity 'Lamda' | Select-Object -ExpandProperty DistinguishedName
```

$dn will now be a string `CN=Lamda,OU=OU_Bloquage,DC=Adminstrateur,DC=6NLG-AD`

To get only the part where it starts with `DC=` from that string there are many options.
For instance:

```
$DN.Substring($dn.IndexOf("DC="))
```

Another way could be:

```
'DC=' + ($DN -split 'DC=', 2)[-1]
```

Or even something like this wil do it:

```
($DN -split '(?<![\\]),' | Where-Object { $_ -match '^DC=' }) -join ','
```

.. and probably a lot more ways to get the desired result